# Same org.w3c.dom.Document variables behave differently

Tags: java, xml, xslt

`w3c.dom.Document` can be used as a `Node`, but when I try this

```
public static Object tranform(Source source) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer newTransformer = tf.newTransformer();
            newTransformer.transform(source, (Result) result);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XMLUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        return result;
    }
```

on the other file

```
     Document doc = (Document) XMLUtils.tranform(source);
     // pass this doc to a function that that a Node typed parameter
     if (node == null) {
         return;
     } else {
         ...
     }
```

`node` would always be null, and it has no child node, too.
I tried to convert every type of source to every type of result, coders will cast the returned result to the correct type they need. So could you please
1) Explain my error?
2) Give me a hint how to implement that purpose?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a class implementing `Result` for instance a `DOMResult`:

```
Result result = new DOMResult();

newTransformer.transform(source, result);

return result.getNode();
```

Comment: Is there any workaround beside specifying the kind of Result inside the transform function? My intend was to create a function that can tranform any kind of source to any kind of result, then the caller can somehow cast the result to the specific type.

Comment: Well you can write a method with return type `Result` but you have to create an instance of a class implementing `Result` to get any result object. And if you want the caller to receive a DOM `Document` or `Node` it needs to be created, passing around `null` values alone does not create any concrete result object. Furthermore I don't think there is a way to cast a `DOMResult` to a DOM `Node`, you need to call the `getNode` method of a `DOMResult`. And if you use other types of result classes there is no way to magically cast them to DOM nodes, as far as I understand the API.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I just assumed that because all types of Result are XML at their core, they should be able to cast to each other.